# Changing year of DataTimeIndex in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a timeseries with data related to the irradiance of the sun. I have data for every hour during a year, but every month has data from a diferent year. For example, the data taken in March can be from 2012 and the data taken in January can be from 2014.

```
T2m RH  G(h)    Gb(n)   Gd(h)   IR(h)   WS10m   WD10m   SP  Hour    Month
time(UTC)                                           
2012-01-01 00:00:00 16.00   81.66   0.0 -0.0    0.0 310.15  2.56    284.0   102252.0    0   1
2012-01-01 01:00:00 15.97   82.42   0.0 -0.0    0.0 310.61  2.49    281.0   102228.0    1   1
2012-01-01 02:00:00 15.93   83.18   0.0 -0.0    0.0 311.06  2.41    278.0   102205.0    2   1
2012-01-01 03:00:00 15.89   83.94   0.0 -0.0    0.0 311.52  2.34    281.0   102218.0    3   1
2012-01-01 04:00:00 15.85   84.70   0.0 -0.0    0.0 311.97  2.26    284.0   102232.0    4   1
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2011-12-31 19:00:00 16.19   77.86   0.0 -0.0    0.0 307.88  2.94    301.0   102278.0    19  12
2011-12-31 20:00:00 16.15   78.62   0.0 -0.0    0.0 308.33  2.86    302.0   102295.0    20  12
2011-12-31 21:00:00 16.11   79.38   0.0 -0.0    0.0 308.79  2.79    297.0   102288.0    21  12
2011-12-31 22:00:00 16.08   80.14   0.0 -0.0    0.0 309.24  2.71    292.0   102282.0    22  12
2011-12-31 23:00:00 16.04   80.90   0.0 -0.0    0.0 309.70  2.64    287.0   102275.0    23  12
```

My question is: there is a way I can set all the data to a certain year?

For example, set all data to 2014

```
T2m RH  G(h)    Gb(n)   Gd(h)   IR(h)   WS10m   WD10m   SP  Hour    Month
time(UTC)                                           
2014-01-01 00:00:00 16.00   81.66   0.0 -0.0    0.0 310.15  2.56    284.0   102252.0    0   1
2014-01-01 01:00:00 15.97   82.42   0.0 -0.0    0.0 310.61  2.49    281.0   102228.0    1   1
2014-01-01 02:00:00 15.93   83.18   0.0 -0.0    0.0 311.06  2.41    278.0   102205.0    2   1
2014-01-01 03:00:00 15.89   83.94   0.0 -0.0    0.0 311.52  2.34    281.0   102218.0    3   1
2014-01-01 04:00:00 15.85   84.70   0.0 -0.0    0.0 311.97  2.26    284.0   102232.0    4   1
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2014-12-31 19:00:00 16.19   77.86   0.0 -0.0    0.0 307.88  2.94    301.0   102278.0    19  12
2014-12-31 20:00:00 16.15   78.62   0.0 -0.0    0.0 308.33  2.86    302.0   102295.0    20  12
2014-12-31 21:00:00 16.11   79.38   0.0 -0.0    0.0 308.79  2.79    297.0   102288.0    21  12
2014-12-31 22:00:00 16.08   80.14   0.0 -0.0    0.0 309.24  2.71    292.0   102282.0    22  12
2014-12-31 23:00:00 16.04   80.90   0.0 -0.0    0.0 309.70  2.64    287.0   102275.0    23  12
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Armen Firman, welcome to stackoverflow! You are usually expected to proide a [minimal *reproducible* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that the community can work from this point on with your code ;)

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`offsets.DateOffset`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html) with `year` (without `s`) for set same year in all `DatetimeIndex`:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2009-04-03', periods=10, freq='350D')
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'a': range(10)}, rng)  
print (df)
            a
2009-04-03  0
2010-03-19  1
2011-03-04  2
2012-02-17  3
2013-02-01  4
2014-01-17  5
2015-01-02  6
2015-12-18  7
2016-12-02  8
2017-11-17  9

df.index += pd.offsets.DateOffset(year=2014)
print (df)
            a
2014-04-03  0
2014-03-19  1
2014-03-04  2
2014-02-17  3
2014-02-01  4
2014-01-17  5
2014-01-02  6
2014-12-18  7
2014-12-02  8
2014-11-17  9
```

Another idea with [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) and `replace`:

```
df.index = df.index.map(lambda x: x.replace(year=2014))
```